# How get rating value from TPFloatRatingView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to get the rating value from TPFloatRatingView, as I can easily implement it and also can pan to update rating view but can't get the value of it. Suggest me how to do it in Objective c.

Comment: Please refer  there is delegate method to track the rating https://github.com/glenyi/TPFloatRatingView/blob/master/TPFloatRatingViewDemo/TPFloatRatingViewDemo/TPViewController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rating` property to get current rating inside the view

```
  ratingView.rating
```

like this

```
 - (void)floatRatingView:(TPFloatRatingView *)ratingView ratingDidChange:(CGFloat)rating
{
   self.ratingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", rating];

   NSLog(@"current rating : %f", ratingView.rating);

}
```

Edit :

```
 self.ratingView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Already tried all possibilities like below but not working, can't get value after completing pan gesture on rating view, code given below:

Comment: -(void)ratingView:(TPFloatRatingView *)ratingView ratingDidChange:(float)rating {
    strRate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", rating];
}
- (void)floatRatingView:(TPFloatRatingView *)ratingView ratingDidChange:(CGFloat)rating {
    strRate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", _ratingView.rating];
    NSLog(@"current rating : %f", ratingView.rating);
}
- (void)floatRatingView:(TPFloatRatingView *)ratingView continuousRating:(CGFloat)rating {
    NSLog(@"current rating : %f", ratingView.rating);
}

Comment: set  self.ratingView.delegate = self;

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delegate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Below are the ways you can set and get the values for rating view(Objective-c),

1) Set :

```
self.tpFloatRatingView.rating = 2.5;
```

2) Get :

```
NSLog(@"Ratting : %f",self.tpFloatRatingView.rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you give rating at that time delegate method called of `TPFloatRatingView`

```
- (void)floatRatingView:(TPFloatRatingView *)ratingView ratingDidChange:(CGFloat)rating {
    NSLog(@"rating = %2.f",rating); //it will print your rate
}
```

in this method `rating` value returns your rating.